# The selection in the LookUpEdit is not saved

Tags: c#, winforms, grid, devexpress

I have in my Grid three columns each one with a `LookUpEditor` inside. Each one displays different data without any problem.

I have set the property `GridView.OptionsBehavior.AutoSelectAllIneditor` to *true* to display an empty row in the bottom to add new data to the grid.

My problem is that when I display the `LookUpEditor` in my first column and select one item and then move to the next column to select another, data my first column does not maintain it's value, and the same with the other column.

Here is the code I used to set my DataSource in the grid and in the LookUpEdit Repository:

```cs
gc_Operaciones.DataSource = _parametroEnsayoProductoList;

repositoryItemLookUpEdit1.DataSource = NBibliography.GetAllElab().Select(p =>   p.NombreProd).ToList();
repositoryItemLookUpEdit2.DataSource = NBibliography.GetAllTypeEnsayo().Select(p => p.Descripcion).ToList();
repositoryItemLookUpEdit3.DataSource = NBibliography.GetAllEnsayo().Select(p => p.Nombre).ToList();
```

Comment: It would be much easier to visualize your problem if you posted your code.

Comment: I just upload my code, but it's very simple, just set the DataSource for each data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that the references to your DataSources are being used between the multiple LookUpEdits.  This has happened to me before and the best way to avoid this situation is to make sure that the data set that is being passed into the LookUpEdit's DataSource is a new object for each of the LookUpEdits.  If you have references to the same data within the multiple LookUpEdits DataSources than the EditValues of the LookUpEdits will change even when you manipulate different LookUpEdits that you have not selected.

Without your code it is difficult for me to code the solution to your issue, but I always just take the data that I need and make sure that I am creating a new copy of the object that I bind to each LookUpEdit's DataSource.  This way each LookUpEdit has it's own set of data and when the data is manipulated it will not interfere with the other LookUpEdits data references.